# Multiple scope urls oauth

Tags: android, google-oauth

I want to get user's email address  and user contacts through Google OAuth.
I have the respective SCOPE urls for both APIs. But how to pass them in one go?

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing it programmatically , in the examples I saw ,usually you should pass an array of strings where each string represents one scope.
If you are doing it via HTTP GET/POST request - just concatenate your scopes with a "+" sign.
like:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile